# Using openlayers 3 to store map tiles on cache

Tags: caching, openlayers-3

Is there any way to cache tiles in the client-side or in the browser cache using openlayers 3? If not, is there any other way?

Comment: Do you use ol3 server side?

Comment: Actually in the client-side, I'm running it from angular, is this possible? I'm planning to use $http to pass the ol.source.XYZ to the server which is of course ran in NodeJS.

Comment: ol.source.XYZ is just an object helping openlayers load and keep track of tiles. The actual tile creation (and caching) is generally done server side. So I'm a little confused by what you mean by saving a ol.source.XYZ to cache?

Comment: I have an external server which there I will get my tiles (through OL3) and render them to the user through ol.source.XYZ, but what if I want to cache this said source to my browser or on local storage? How will I do that?

Comment: So is your question about caching/saving tiles client side (used for performance or offline capabilities), or about server side caches (used for performance and server resource optimizations)?

Comment: Just changed the question. Yes what i need is on the client-side..